# subversion update does not replace my local changes with the latest file

Tags: php, svn, netbeans, svn-update

I am working on a PHP project in Netbeans, using subversion for version control. I have made local changes to a file and saved without committing. My coworker made changes and commitments to the file later today. When I update the file, it leaves my current file intact, but when I go to history it shows the latest version of the file-- my coworker's edits-- and I can diff to it and see many changes.

Why hasn't the update completely replaced the local edits I made? Am I missing something, or is that the default behavior of subversion? If I run an update, I would expect to have the updated file, not a file which includes my uncommitted edits.

I'm new to subversion, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell subversion to overwrite your local changes.  Overwrite and Update in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! I am actually using netbeans though, so any idea how to do it there? My svn menu only has `Update`, and `update to...` which lets you "update" to a previous version I think.

Comment: I am not a big NetBeans user myself..... I was able to find this however. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html#merging

Comment: Ah, I think my IDE's default update behavior has been set to merge, so I'll need to mess with some settings there. Thanks for the info